AWS Cognito Auth JSON request isn't Deserializing with nested classes in Unity
My JSON request isn't Deserializing with my nested classes in Unity.
I have tried many things to figure this problem out. Can someone spot the issue?
Here is the JSON Login Request from AWS Cognito:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-17T02:14:10.331Z",
    "level": "INFO",
    "requestId": "2dc7b590-1827-4554-9821-908eb1d3ee3f",
    "message": {
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "requestId": "0c684225-7a1b-469f-89e3-15d29da36f49",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
        "ChallengeParameters": {
            "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "348844c8-e001-7030-93c4-3c5a5a754fa2",
            "requiredAttributes": "[]",
            "userAttributes": "{\"email_verified\":\"true\",\"preferred_username\":\"RobloxHero\",\"email\":\"robloxhero@compassoftruth.org\"}"
        },
        "Session": "AYABeHuZceyPXQVTVA1OPXwrdZIAHQABAAdTZXJ2aWNlABBDb2duaXRvVXNlclBvb2xzAAEAB2F3cy1rbXMAS2Fybjphd3M6a21zOnVzLWVhc3QtMTo3NDU2MjM0Njc1NTU6a2V5L2IxNTVhZmNhLWJmMjktNGVlZC1hZmQ4LWE5ZTA5MzY1M2RiZQC4AQIBAHjHL4WD3WpekpFe85nxP9Nwg99u3bPN6BTSaB-uHZcTLAF1FxlVsAaSp8ntnWxXieO7AAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMjuV5Bhw0j4lWg6JxAgEQgDusJsldE8RrnX72vgmOQkw9KkrzbARBsxGkfjRqS5A6T7T71F6umtOTz7XnjEqdeAfhfyQ2vT_Hmx2-nAIAAAAADAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABejP7rYrS09IQqwZHglO_k_____wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAADVlPZSlzCXntBx_E8TEbzxbn4ZTZBEr5nMSXRinXYnmVRrlKjtLX7yv8giRh1z1_rYNSKGAY2b3cz1PyWadtwifpldG6_d3NdgthTaMpQNeIhJ_jmjfz0U_4hrYWVyz5OspPbR38Rlelj5r9DIQaGWGFMVVDuzeeouxbBTl83O3w5Rx2gYYZ3AmyIBrMiVxDscytZj8oJ4fit76lVlFlFNmwMywy6MjhDb80RGcYoUpkbUZn86X1Ycy5KZstb7tm4dFp7IN1ej69IcLmYZbvcJ4xBCZeEJCrfccFbdhVG0zGcPUB1lzw"
    }
}

Here is the The Unity Plugin Code I'm making a JSON Requesting to Login:
public void LoginRequest()
    {
        AWSUserLoginRequest request = new AWSUserLoginRequest();
        request.username = username;
        request.password = password;

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://game-api.compassoftruth.org/prod/Login", JsonUtility.ToJson(request), "application/json") )
        {
            www.SendWebRequest();
            while (www.isDone == false) {
            //do something, or nothing while blocking
            }
            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else {
                LoginResult = JsonUtility.FromJson<AWSLoginResult>(www.downloadHandler.text.Replace('$'.ToString(), ""));
                // Show results as text
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text.Replace('$'.ToString(), ""));
                Debug.Log(LoginResult.level);
            }
        }
        
    }

I'm able to debug the response data in string format:
{"metadata":{"httpStatusCode":200,"requestId":"731de9a0-a3b3-4a75-a565-f19c49f19a50","attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0},"ChallengeName":"NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED","ChallengeParameters":{"USER_ID_FOR_SRP":"348844c8-e001-7030-93c4-3c5a5a754fa2","requiredAttributes":"[]","userAttributes":"{\"email_verified\":\"true\",\"preferred_username\":\"RobloxHero\",\"email\":\"robloxhero@compassoftruth.org\"}"},"Session":"AYABeJlFAr90U2rURQa1RoyPy-AAHQABAAdTZXJ2aWNlABBDb2duaXRvVXNlclBvb2xzAAEAB2F3cy1rbXMAS2Fybjphd3M6a21zOnVzLWVhc3QtMTo3NDU2MjM0Njc1NTU6a2V5L2IxNTVhZmNhLWJmMjktNGVlZC1hZmQ4LWE5ZTA5MzY1M2RiZQC4AQIBAHjHL4WD3WpekpFe85nxP9Nwg99u3bPN6BTSaB-uHZcTLAH4F1Ox2jph9NZcOwFtL6m-AAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQM7FLUPDofg4S5f67nAgEQgDsIOeZuVErT75jsNRBJz63Pat7GgObkPeKx7Li_z5tvnDG4FvrbLoLjVcgJpVin-rz9Cp_bcfmxyjX0owIAAAAADAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtqnLZ5SIekFGUo3n6YKYi_____wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAADV0iUMK4jkW4ioIy8AGcb5bLTQ3jW90JXuaucWAlImLuT55a3TaWyStOL_O6uJb-2NDqz7ejkQ3eUDlMn02AYwvj75cI4bB6nuaOSomjBZ4-tkT8AtpbykIYTgc451wjg5U9CrnbbTViMR-s3Fdx6P_rABop_INWkf1lAUs1xrlY5AMX3VGc2bjlHX9Ejips9irlVpnuUXic-AJXQUcZeHbi9DmcfSFe0VDTQGWMJmLFUZFWfJAQeo-dvQadfvkm2r1Lwwn42WGVkPykxbVqdkTUxIUcpFajlRAZp5B4PRxoJCBp-CVA"}


And here is my nested classed that I'm using to try and parse the info with JSONUtility:
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.VersionControl;

[Serializable]
public class AWSLoginResult
{
    public string timestamp;
    public string level;
    public string requestId;
    public message message; 

}

[Serializable]
public class message
{
    public string ChallangeName;
    public ChallangeParameters ChallangeParameters;
    public string Session;
}

[Serializable]
public class ChallangeParameters
{
    public string USER_ID_FOR_SRP;
    public string userAttributes;
    public string requiredAttributes;

}



You have shown us a lot of code, but what is your specific issue? What is the problem and what were you wanting to achieve? Is there an error message? Or perhaps some output that seems wrong? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Do you want my post to entertain someone with debugging skills to help?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My classes in C# were using the whole logs object from AWS Logs...
I needed to only use the console logged object from node.js, the "message".
Changing my classes to mirror the correct object looks like this.
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.VersionControl;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

[Serializable]
public class AWSLoginResult
{
    public metadata metadata;
    public string ChallengeName;
    public ChallangeParameters ChallangeParameters;
    public string Session;

}

[Serializable]
public class metadata
{
    public string httpStatusCode;
    public string requestId;
    public string attempts;
    public string totalRetryDelay;

}

[Serializable]
public class ChallangeParameters
{
    public string USER_ID_FOR_SRP;
    public string userAttributes;
    public string requiredAttributes;

}


